# JavaScript in Zapier to loop API calls using pagination

Tags: javascript, python, json, api, zapier

I have a GET request in Zapier using this API to get a list of yoga classes from booking system MindBody; https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/PublicDocumentation/V6#get-classes

Zapier does have a feature to automatically GET ‘all’ results even the max Limit is 200 and the Zap needs to GET the next page of results.  By default, I can get a Limit of 200 results with offset of 0.

I need Zapier to Get the first 200, increase the offset by 200, get results 200-400, and so on. The end result would could be 650 results all combined in the Zap that I can then use in another task (Count, sum, find, etc)

How do I use Zapier Code task to incrementally loop/GET all items in a JSON list using these parameters:

Example pagination information returned in the response body:

https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/PublicDocumentation/V6#pagination

{
    "PaginationResponse": {
        "RequestedLimit": 10,
        "RequestedOffset": 20,
        "PageSize": 10,
        "TotalResults": 128
    },
    "Classes": [
        . . .
    ]
}

Sample GET and response in Zapier today;

SAMPLE DATA IN (GET Request)

json_key:Visits
unflatten:yes
headers:
Content-Type:application/json
SiteId:xxx
API-Key:xxx
Name:xxx
url:https://api.mindbodyonline.com/public/v6/client/clientvisits
data:
Limit:200
StartDate:2015-01-01T00:00:00
EndDate:2099-01-01T00:00:00
ClientID:xxx
Offset:0
As_json:no

SAMPLE DATA RETURNED

Visits:
1:
 ClassId:xxx
 LastModifiedDateTime:0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
 MakeUp:false
 AppointmentId:0
 ServiceName:
 AppointmentGenderPreference:None
 EndDateTime:2019-12-11T08:15:00
 ClientId:xxx
 LateCancelled:false
 Action:None
 ServiceId:
 SiteId:xxx
 SignedIn:true
 StartDateTime:2019-12-11T07:15:00
 StaffId:x
 LocationId:x
 WebSignup:false
 ProductId:
 AppointmentStatus:None
 Id:xxx
 Name:xxx
2:
 ClassId:xxx
 LastModifiedDateTime:0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
 MakeUp:false
 AppointmentId:0
 ServiceName:
 AppointmentGenderPreference:None
 EndDateTime:2019-12-11T09:30:00
 ClientId:xxx
 LateCancelled:false
 Action:None
 ServiceId:
 SiteId:xxx
 SignedIn:true
 StartDateTime:2019-12-11T08:30:00
 StaffId:xxx
 LocationId:xx
 WebSignup:false
 ProductId:
 AppointmentStatus: None
 Id:xxx
 Name:xxx

PaginationResponse:
 TotalResults:2
 PageSize:2
 RequestedOffset:0
 RequestedLimit:

**UPDATE 12/19/2019:**
1) Call endpoint; https://api.mindbodyonline.com/public/v6/client/clientvisits with query params;
 StartDate: 2015-01-01T00:00:00
 EndDate: 2099-01-01T00:00:00
 Offset: 0
 ClientID: XXX
 Limit: 200
Headers;
 Name: xxx
 SiteId: xxx
 Api-Key: xxx
 Content-Type: application/json

Sample Response in Postman:
{
    "PaginationResponse": {
        "RequestedLimit": 200,
        "RequestedOffset": 0,
        "PageSize": 2,
        "TotalResults": 2
    },
    "Visits": [
        {
            "AppointmentId": 0,
            "AppointmentGenderPreference": "None",
            "AppointmentStatus": "None",
            "ClassId": xxx,
            "ClientId": "xxx",
            "StartDateTime": "2019-04-27T09:45:00",
            "EndDateTime": "2019-04-27T10:45:00",
            "Id": xxx,
            "LastModifiedDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "LateCancelled": false,
            "LocationId": 1,
            "MakeUp": false,
            "Name": "Yoga Barre",
            "ServiceId": null,
            "SignedIn": true,
            "StaffId": xxx,
            "WebSignup": false,
            "Action": "None"
        },
        {
            "AppointmentId": 0,
            "AppointmentGenderPreference": "None",
            "AppointmentStatus": "None",
            "ClassId": xxx,
            "ClientId": "xxx",
            "StartDateTime": "2019-07-19T16:45:00",
            "EndDateTime": "2019-07-19T17:45:00",
            "Id": 273726,
            "LastModifiedDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "LateCancelled": false,
            "LocationId": 1,
            "MakeUp": false,
            "Name": "Meditation",
            "ServiceId": null,
            "SignedIn": true,
            "StaffId": xxx,
            "WebSignup": false,
            "Action": "None"
        }
   ]
}

IF the TotalResults = 201 or more, the requested offset should be set to 200 and loop again, and so on.  The only data I need in the response is "SignedIn" which I can have zapier count or sum in a later step if all of the ClientVisits are collected together.  Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Are you doing this in Developer or via a Zap with Code by Zapier?

Comment: Code.  Developer has pagination but per Zapier support, the pagination is a feature the user has to manually call.  Sounds like Code, as a task in the Zap, needs to increment/loop the pagination requests.  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Okay, so I think what we need to know to get you an answer is as follows. 1- Each Zap step name in order and vital data variables within them(picture may be better). 2 - Where the data is going after pagination (first question may answer this). Some zaps wont support pagination even if you code it correctly. 3 - API code that you have so far (use dummy names for private info like tokens).

Comment: Thank you!  Here is what happens in the Zap now and works.  I count the 'SignedIn:True' as the end result.

Comment: I updated the question with sample GET and response.  sample data is retiurning a list of 2 classes with their attributes.  You will see the Pagination response at the end.  If the TOTALRESULTS is greater than 200, the GET needs to happen again with OFFSET:200 to get results 200-400.

Comment: Okay so currently you do not have any JavaScript or Python written up? I think I can write up something simple to test it with if you havent. Also, are you sending the get request to this URL: https://api.mindbodyonline.com/public/v6/client/clientvisits

Comment: @littlecoder Yes, this is the URL and I dont have anything written today.  The trigger will come in from a webhook (which is already setup) and the Zapier Code action will call this URL until no more results are available.  The attribute I;m looking for in the response is "SignedIn" which is true or false.  Once these are all collected, I can use another Zap to count all of the SigneIn responses that are "True" thus giving me to the total number of classes someone actually signed in for!

Comment: @JohnStuart what is the nature of the webhook (trigger)? Is it a GET request to a mindbodyonline endpoint or is it catching a POST from the mindbodyonline API? Could you share some screen shots of each step as littlecoder requested? Any thoughts on the answer I provided?

Comment: @MichaelCase Hi Michael - Thanks for your response and I'm preparing a response for you based on your great Python outline.  I'll get you a few screenshots too but the trigger is already setup and working fine.  The Trigger will initiate the Python code to GET additional data from MindBody endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the Python code module offered by Zapier to achieve this. From what you have described thus far it seems like you are using the webhooks zap which is very useful for quickly making HTTP requests but can lack in fine tuning aspects.

I am not sure what trigger you would like to use to have this zap flow execute so I will just assume you would like it to happen at a specific time once per day. So we use the scheduler zap as the trigger. The action step will be code by Zapier using the Python module. Please see the code below:

```py
import requests

def send_request(url):

    headers = {
        "Api-Key" : "yourApiKey",
        "SiteId" : "yourSiteID",
        "Authorization" : "staffUserToken"
        }

    result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return result



def main():

    offset = 0
    limit = 50
    total_results = 0
    class_data = []

    while True:
        result = send_request(f"api.mindbodyonline.com/public/v6/ckass/classes?limit={limit}&offset={offset}")

        if not result.ok: # Bad request
            break

        result = result.json()

        if not total_results:
            total_results = result.get('PaginationResponse', {}).get('TotalResults', 0)

        if offset >= total_results: # We have exceeded the total number of results available
            break

        temp_class_data = result.get('Classes')
        for data in temp_class_data:
            class_data.append({
                    "ClassScheduleID" : data.get("ClassScheduleID"),
                    "Clients" : data.get("Clients"),
                    "MaxCapacity" : data.get("MaxCapacity"),
                    "TotalBooked" : data.get("TotalBooked")
                    })

        offset += limit

    return class_data

return main()
```

Using Python's requests library you can formulate your own HTTP requests. We can paginate through the results using a while loop to increment our offset variable. I don't use this service so I chose some arbitrary data points to return for whatever step you would like to use next. With the code above I am returning a list of dictionary objects. Because of this any subsequent action steps will execute on each unique result. So if after running the above code my `class_data` list holds 3 separate results the following action steps will execute on each of those steps individually.

Hopefully this helps. I made a few assumptions about what you are trying to achieve. Let me know if anything is unclear or you have any additional questions.

Comment: 1) Call endpoint https://api.mindbodyonline.com/public/v6/client/clientvisits with query params

Comment: I guess I can't put screen shots into these comments so I uopdated the question.  See "**UPDATE 12/19/2019:**" with endpoint, params, and sample Postman response.  Thanks!